# Replacement for \curveto in the tikz library - Inkscape export svg to tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, svg, inkscape

I need to draw a complex curve and I wanted to help a vector program Inkscape.
In first step I tried to use Inkscape to TikZ exporter (http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/)to convert curve to tikz, but unsuccessfully (error occured after start of the plugin - Inkscape 0.48.2 r9819/Extension/Export/Export to Tikz path). It is unlikely that someone with me to help with this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "tikz_export.py", line 1391, in <module>

    main_inkscape()

  File "tikz_export.py", line 1379, in main_inkscape

    effect.affect()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\share\extensions\inkex.py", line 216, in affect

    if output: self.output()

  File "tikz_export.py", line 1322, in output

    f = codecs.open(self.options.outputfile, 'w', 'utf8')

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\python\Lib\codecs.py", line 870, in open

    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'none'
```

So I would like to ask how could be replaced command `\curveto` by native tikz command. Because I'm able to convert Inkscape curve to PSTricks... I'm more familiar with pakcage tikz.

```
%LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
%%Creator: 0.48.2
%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(272,129)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linewidth=1,linecolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(1.410771,63.47461)
\curveto(6.288991,93.43519)(6.900971,94.37507)(27.182131,102.49149)
\curveto(41.727261,108.31238)(35.032981,125.42937)(51.364001,125.36952)
\curveto(67.695031,125.30962)(67.928601,83.44326)(69.419751,64.22647)
\curveto(70.630951,48.61748)(74.370481,32.72818)(94.65164,24.61178)
\curveto(109.19677,18.79088)(101.39868,1.81368)(117.97023,1.87438)
\curveto(134.06073,1.93338)(134.11602,42.07748)(136.03504,63.349)
\curveto(136.94551,73.44118)(139.86205,86.13389)(143.15997,91.12848)
\curveto(146.45789,96.12308)(151.68117,98.38715)(161.82175,102.44536)
\curveto(176.36688,108.26625)(169.6726,125.38324)(186.00362,125.32339)
\curveto(202.33465,125.26349)(199.36351,96.7115)(204.05937,64.18034)
\curveto(208.75523,31.64918)(209.0101,32.68208)(229.29126,24.56568)
\curveto(243.83639,18.74478)(236.0383,1.76758)(252.60985,1.82828)
\curveto(268.70035,1.88728)(256.58629,30.46878)(270.65931,63.2234)
}
}
\end{pspicture}
```

I guess it could solve command `control`, but I still have not succeeded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(It looks like Inkscape couldn't open a file for writing to.)

The following "works" with your example.  If all your generated code is like that then it might work with that, but it isn't a full solution.

The direct replacement for `\curveto` is `\pgfpathcurveto`.  So you could redefine the PSTricks macros to their PGF equivalents (where such exist) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82308/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\moveto(#1,#2){%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{#1 pt}{#2 pt}}}

\def\curveto(#1,#2)(#3,#4)(#5,#6){%
  \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{#1 pt}{#2 pt}}{\pgfpoint{#3 pt}{#4 pt}}{\pgfpoint{#5 pt}{#6 pt}}}

\let\psset=\tikzset
\def\pscustom[#1]{\tikzset{#1}}
\tikzset{
  xunit/.style={x={(#1,0)}},
  yunit/.style={y={(0,#1)}},
  runit/.style={},
  linecolor/.style={color=#1},
  linewidth/.style={line width=#1},
}

\def\newrgbcolor#1#2{\definecolor{#1}{RGB}{#2}}
\def\pspicture(#1,#2){\tikzpicture}
\def\endpspicture{%
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\endtikzpicture}
\let\newpath=\relax


\begin{document}

%LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
%%Creator: 0.48.2
%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(272,129)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linewidth=1,linecolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(1.410771,63.47461)
\curveto(6.288991,93.43519)(6.900971,94.37507)(27.182131,102.49149)
\curveto(41.727261,108.31238)(35.032981,125.42937)(51.364001,125.36952)
\curveto(67.695031,125.30962)(67.928601,83.44326)(69.419751,64.22647)
\curveto(70.630951,48.61748)(74.370481,32.72818)(94.65164,24.61178)
\curveto(109.19677,18.79088)(101.39868,1.81368)(117.97023,1.87438)
\curveto(134.06073,1.93338)(134.11602,42.07748)(136.03504,63.349)
\curveto(136.94551,73.44118)(139.86205,86.13389)(143.15997,91.12848)
\curveto(146.45789,96.12308)(151.68117,98.38715)(161.82175,102.44536)
\curveto(176.36688,108.26625)(169.6726,125.38324)(186.00362,125.32339)
\curveto(202.33465,125.26349)(199.36351,96.7115)(204.05937,64.18034)
\curveto(208.75523,31.64918)(209.0101,32.68208)(229.29126,24.56568)
\curveto(243.83639,18.74478)(236.0383,1.76758)(252.60985,1.82828)
\curveto(268.70035,1.88728)(256.58629,30.46878)(270.65931,63.2234)
}
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: PGF Path]

What I would do in such a circumstance is actually use something like the above to generate a pgf soft path, then cut-and-paste that into my real document.  I wouldn't use hacks like the above in a proper document.

Answer (score 0):

Just if someone gets here looking for the inkscape2tikz error, the problem is that the inkscape does not have permission to write the export file, the export file gets written within the extensions directory without asking where to be saved. Therefore if the user executing inkscape does not have permission to write in the extensions folder it crashes and thats the error given.

> Inkscape to TikZ exporter (http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/)