# pictograms, Iconography, scalable shapes, custom nodes, shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, scaling

Hy,

I'm building up my own iconography, a set of pictograms that represent ideas so that i can connect them to illustrate more complex systems. I would like some suggestions of which is the best manner to do that. How can I do a library of pictograms? how shall i add them to my schemes? which is best and easiest way to draw blocks like the ones shown in the example image (i.e. the protractor and the ruler)? would they scale properly?

I looked at the [pigs example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parameterised-pig/) but is quite non-intuitive. Any reading suggestions?

Thanks for the guidance. 
[image]

Comment: **10** Draw them in a vector graphics software **20** find the svg file convert it to TikZ code **30** Find the bitmap, use `potrace` to convert it to vector **40** goto 30 **50** end

Comment: 30 is not clear to me. I don't understand why once is in TikZ there's the need of export them to bitmap and then use potrace to convert them into a vector and how gets the Eps included inside the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: I mean use this picture you have and trace it not export it if you have it already

Comment: Is there any other way to convert svg to tikz rather than inkscape2tikz. I get the exact same nasty  [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82308/replacement-for-curveto-in-the-tikz-library-inkscape-export-svg-to-tikz](error) and i get stuck without exporting the file. 

Using root user seems to go through but it saves nowhere, the file is not there

Comment: Using root it gets through, sorry. The file gets stored within the extension folder.

Comment: You absolutely should not do this kind of thing as root! If you need to, either you are doing something very, very misguided or your system is very, very screwed up. (And if it is not yet the latter, it will be soon due to the former.)

Comment: Similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147389/symbols-of-pencil-ruler-and-compass.

Comment: you MUST never execute as root. That's a given. However sometimes if (and only if) you trust the software you can execute as root in order to trace what is gufy. So yes, I did execute that as a root once, realize what was fishy fix it, and moved on.

Comment: Did the former comments help you? Is there any progress so far? Maybe you can even provide a self answer by now?