# symbols of pencil, ruler and compass

Tags: symbols

How can I produce the codes to get the symbols of pencil, ruler and compass in `LATEX`? I'm gonna write a sentence `I can draw this figure by using simple tools` in my presentation. So I prefer to include symbols pencil, ruler and compass instead of the words `simple tools`. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried looking up these symbols in the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)? That at least has a symbol for a pencil.

Comment: @Adam --- there are assorted pencil symbols in the comprehensive list, but I cannot see ruler or compass symbols.

Comment: @IanThompson, I just noticed that myself and changed my comment because of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam, thank you! I found some kinds of pencils. Nothing for compasses and rulers.

Comment: Surely it is clear from the comments that these symbols cannot be obtained by the 'usual' means. Therefore I don't think the question is a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21/2417). There is [a question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3921/2417) relevant to this situation on the meta site.

Comment: @user53541: Take a look at [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com). They have Creative Commons licensed icons of [compasses](http://thenounproject.com/noun/drafting-compass/#icon-No10249), [pencils](http://thenounproject.com/noun/pencil/#icon-No347) and [rulers](http://thenounproject.com/noun/ruler/#icon-No1693).

Comment: @Jake and presumably use inkscape to convert svg to pstricks, then compile with latex->dvips...?

Comment: @ChrisH: that, or use `pdflatex` to compile, or use `pdftoeps` to convert the PDF.

Comment: @Jake or a couple of other routes I guess (there's an inkscape->Tikz extension now, which I'd like to try, but can't run inkscape extensions on this box due to python version issues)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First a pencil:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=30]
            \fill[gray!50] (0,4) -- (0.4,4) -- (0.4,0) --(0.3,-0.15) -- (0.2,0) -- (0.1,-0.14) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
            \draw[color=white] (0.2,4) -- (0.2,0);
            \fill[black] (0,3.5) -- (0.2,3.47) -- (0.4,3.5) -- (0.4,4) arc(30:150:0.23cm);
            \fill[brown!40] (0,0) -- (0.2,-0.8)node[coordinate,pos=0.75](a){} -- (0.4,0)node[coordinate,pos=0.25](b){} -- (0.3,-0.15) -- (0.2,0) -- (0.1,-0.14) -- cycle;
            \fill[gray] (a) -- (0.2,-0.8) -- (b) -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And a scale (ruler):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-30,transform shape]
            \draw (-0.2,0) rectangle (15.5,1);
            %% lower divisions
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,15}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,0.2)node[above,scale=0.4]{\x};
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,14.9}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,0.075);
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,14.5}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,0.15);
            }
            % Upper divisions
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}{
            \draw (\x in,1) -- (\x in,0.8)node[below,scale=0.4]{\x};
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,5.9}{
            \draw (\x in,1) -- (\x in,0.925);
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,5.5}{
            \draw (\x in,1) -- (\x in,0.85);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And a compass:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=0,transform shape]
    %\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
       \draw (2.95,3.7) rectangle (3,3.95);
       \draw (2.92,3.68) -- (2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,2.3) -- (2.99,3.68);
       \draw (3.5,2.5) -- (3.43,2.48);
       \draw (3.04,3.68) -- (3.5,2.5) -- (3.5,2.3) -- (2.975,3.68);
       \draw (2.5,2.5) -- (2.56,2.48);
       \draw[fill=white] (2.975,3.75) circle (0.1cm);
       \draw (2.975,3.75) circle (0.04cm);
       \draw (2.5,3.2) -- (3.5,3.2);
       \draw[line width = 0.5pt,line cap=round] (2.975,3.15) -- (2.975,3.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: exellent examples of tikz! thank you for sharing that!

Comment: You should package this for CTAN so you don't forget about it ;). Seriously, I think this would make a good TikZ library. Symbols are just the kinds of things which lend themselves to being reused in multiple contexts. Especially if they were `pic`s.

Comment: Excellent ! Can I use these forms in my next tkz-euclide documentation?

Comment: @AlainMatthes: By all means please. It is my pleasure. :)

Comment: @cfr A package was created, using some of this code: https://ctan.org/pkg/outilsgeomtikz (see the footnote 1 of the documentation). The name of the package is from "Tools geometry Ti*k*Z" in french. It features pens, compass, rules, ...

Answer (score 4):

The new package [**outilsgeomtikz**](https://ctan.org/pkg/outilsgeomtikz) features some of these objets. The name **outilsgeomtikz** is for the French words Outils géométrie Ti*k*Z (Tools geometry Ti*k*Z). I'm not the author.

[image]

(image taken from the cover page of the documentation)

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but maybe it's helpful some people (like me): there is a package [pst-geometrictools](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-geometrictools): *"draw­ing of pro­trac­tors, rulers, com­passes and pen­cils."*