# Drawing 3D surfaces with triangles (to show curvature effects)

Tags: diagrams, 3d

I'm looking for a way to draw 3D surfaces in LaTeX with triangles on them to show the sum of angles being >, =, or < 180 degrees, exactly as in this photo

[image: this photo]
<sub>(source: [space.com](http://i.space.com/images/i/000/036/078/original/universe-shape.jpg?1389843216))</sub>
.

I'd just like to do it myself, but I'm rather overwhelmed by the array of options available, and not sure where to start (nor how to do it). Thank you.

Comment: Of the tools often discussed here, then Asymptote is probably the most capable for 3D graphics.  But perhaps you would prefer to draw this with a tool like Mathematica and generate a graphics file that you could include in your LaTeX document with `graphicx` package?  Or even just include this picture?

Comment: This might be of help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254820/tikz-pair-of-compasse-rendering-contest/254866?s=2|0.4408#254866

Comment: Another possibility could be use GeoGebra as described [here](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121battaia-3d.pdf)

Comment: This can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446325/a-hyperbolic-triangle-embedded-in-a-saddle-shaped-surface?noredirect=1&lq=1