# How do I draw an arc from an axis to an arbitrary point tikz-3dplot?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I've been attempting to draw an arc (α) from a point on the Z/Z' axis to a point on v. I have been unable to find an example that lets me solve this problem. I can create something that looks good for this particular system. However, I would like something more general for other work I have to do in the near future.

How would I go about drawing an arc between the Z/Z' axis and an arbitrary point P?

I present, for your review, a copy of my code and the image it produces.

```
\documentclass[border = 10pt, 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{limegreen}{rgb}{0.2, 0.8, 0.2}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{-30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale=4]

%Draws Main Frame
\draw[line width = 2, -stealth] (0,0,0) --(2,0,0) node[above = 3] {\Large{$X$}} ;
\draw[line width = 2, -stealth] (0,0,0) --(0,2,0) node[below = 2] {\Large{$Y$}} ;
\draw[line width = 2, -stealth] (0,0,0) --(0,0,2) node[right = 2] {\Large{$Z$}} ;

%Draws rotated frame
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords, line width = 2, -stealth, red, dashed] (0,0,0) --(2,0,0) node[above = 3] {\Large{$X'$}} ;
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords, line width = 2, -stealth, red, dashed] (0,0,0) --(0,2,0) node[below = 2] {\Large{$Y'$}} ;  
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords, line width = 2, -stealth, red, dashed] (0,0,0) --(0,0,2) node[left = 2] {\Large{$Z'$}} ;   

%Draw vector in main frame
\draw[line width = 2, -stealth, limegreen ] (0,0,0) --(2,2,2) node[right = 2] {\Large{$\vec{v}$}} ;

%Draw vector in rotated frame
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords, line width = 2, -stealth, blue] (0,0,0) --(2,2,2) node[left = 2] {\Large{$\vec{v}'$}} ;

%draws rotation
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z = 0, line width = 1, domain = 90:60, -latex,red] plot ({.75*cos(\x)}, {.75*sin(\x)});
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z = 0, line width = 1, domain = 0:-30, -latex,red] plot ({.75*cos(\x)}, {.75*sin(\x)}) ;
\tdplotdrawarc[-stealth, line width = 1, red]{(0,0,1)}{1.414}{45}{15}{anchor=north}{\Large{$d\psi$}}

%Labels rotations
\node [red] at (.25, .875, 0) {\Large{$d\psi$}};
\node [red] at (.95, -.2, 0) {\Large{$d\psi$}};
%draws dv
\draw[line width = 1, -stealth, blue] (2,2,2) -- node[above = 3] {\Large{$d\vec{v}$}} (2.732051,0.732051,2);
%draws alpha
\draw[line width = 1] (0,0,1) -- node[above = 3] {\Large{$\alpha$}} (1,1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Arcs are always drawn in the current xy plane.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254820/tikz-pair-of-compasse-rendering-contest/254866?s=2|0.4447#254866