# Computer and save symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, ctan

How can I write a computer/pc symbol [computer/pc symbol](http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/11/2701/Computer-1127235136.png) and a [save symbol](http://www.somerandomdude.com/wp-content/uploads/save-icon.png) in LaTeX? I looked in the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) but don't find them.

Comment: Have you had a look at fontawesome?

Comment: Why does `\usepackage{fontawesome}` not work? It returns "Error: file 'fontawesome.sty' not found.

Comment: Probably because it is not installed. Which distribution do you use?

Comment: I use TeXShop 2.47 or is this not the distribution. (I'm not used to working with fonts.)

Comment: Here I show how to do it with other available icons that are available as graphical images, in a way that automatically scales with font size.  You can literally substitute your icon file name in its place.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270351/a-ruler-symbol-in-latex/270352#270352

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your comment is what I was looking for. Could you repeat is as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I would love to, but cannot link to your PC symbol nor save symbol.  Might they look something like http://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/composite/78,08/computer-icon-vector-107808.jpg and http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Programming-Save-icon.png?  Better still, why don't you include them in your question as actual images rather than links?

Answer (score 2):

If you have trouble finding the symbols you are looking for in a font, or if you are unable to install the right font package, you can use the image files that you used in your question. You can specify the size of the image using the `height` attribute of `\includegraphics`. You can define a macro to save some typing if you use this icon multiple times (see `\asav` below). With a little more effort you can get the current font size and display the icon using this size, scaling it proportional to the text (see `\bsav` below).
Examples:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\mytextsize}

\newcommand{\asav}[0]{\includegraphics[height=20pt]{save-icon.png}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bsav}[0]{\setlength{\mytextsize}{\f@size pt}\includegraphics[height=\mytextsize]{save-icon.png} }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Press the \includegraphics{save-icon.png} button to save
\item Press the \includegraphics[height=20pt]{save-icon.png} button to save
\item Press the \asav button to save
\item Press the \bsav button to save
\item \tiny Press the \bsav button to save
\item \normalsize Press the \bsav button to save
\item \huge Press the \bsav button to save
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```