# Place a ruler somewhere on a page

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How can I place a virtual ruler (which accurately measures distance) on a page, irrespective of page margins? For example, along the left-hand side of the page from the top to the bottom.

Basically, I'm trying to find a LaTeX equivalent of making a custom document class, printing out a Lorem Ipsum version of that document, and measuring the margins by hand. I've seen [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270359/109799) showing how to make a ruler in TikZ, but I don't know how to **1)** change the length of the ruler easily (e.g., `\ruler{10}{in}` for a 10" ruler) and, more importantly, **2)** place the ruler on the page so I can measure page margins.

Thanks to anyone who can give an answer or help point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe **package `layout`** will help. It provides the command `\layout` which inserts one (onesided document) or two (twosided documents) pages that show the relevant sizes of the current page layout.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}% needed if the format of the document differs from the settings of your TeX system
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
  \layout
\end{document}
```

Odd page:

[image]

Even page:

[image]

---

Or you can use **package `scrlayer`**. Then you can define a new page style using a layer with `contents=\layercontentsmeasure`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  innermargin,
  contents=\layercontentsmeasure
]{measurelayer}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{measurestyle}{measurelayer}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\Blindtext
\pagestyle{measurestyle}
\clearpage
\Blindtext
\clearpage
\pagestyle{headings}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are other predefined layer areas like `topmargin`, `head`, `headsep`, `textarea`,... But you can also define the size and the position of a layer:

```
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  hoffset=1cm,
  voffset=.5cm,
  width=2cm,
  height=10cm,
  contents=\layercontentsmeasure
]{measurelayer}
```

[image]

Or you can modify a predefined layer area:

```
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  topmargin,
  addheight=\dimexpr\headheight+\headsep\relax,
  contents=\layercontentsmeasure
]{measurelayer}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Instead of a ruler you could put a grid behind the text with `eso-pic` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[grid,
  gridcolor=red!20,
  subgridcolor=green!20,
  gridunit=in]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Attention, copy-paste programmers like myself: One of the parameters says `gridunit=in`, that's why the numbers are so strange.

Answer (score 12):

There is a new package for this aim, namely `fgruler`:

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fgruler

For example, try the following simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[type=none]{fgruler}
\begin{document}
\fgruler{upperleft}{1cm}{2cm}
text
\ruler{rightup}{3cm}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use my answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831) to put something anywhere on the page.  Then, I go to the web and find a nice transparent ruler, for example, at https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/12/52/ruler-146428_960_720.png.  Then I crop it to 30.5 virtual centimeters width.  Finally, I `\includegraphics[width=30.5cm]{}` it with my `\atxy` macro to overlay it anywhere on the page.  Because of its transparancy, one can take measurements of what lies underneath.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\begin{document}
\atxy{0in}{4in}{\includegraphics[width=30.5cm]{ruler-146428_960_720(cropped)}}
\atxy{1in}{10in}{\rotatebox{20}{%
  \includegraphics[width=30.5cm]{ruler-146428_960_720(cropped)}}}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]