# PSTricks and XeLateX issue

Tags: xetex, pstricks

Since updating to MacTeX 2021 my pstricks files don't compile anymore. I've been searching for the solution but the ones suggested don't seem to work (e. g. using xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" in TeXShop).

For example, MWE from [A ruler symbol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270351/a-ruler-symbol-in-latex)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.2,1.5)(10.2,3)
    \psframe[linecolor=lightgray](-.2,1.5)(10.2,3)
    \multips(0,3)(0.1,0){101}{\psline(0,-.1)}
    \multips(0,3)(0.5,0){21}{\psline(0,-.2)}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,10}{\rput(\x,3){\psline(0,-.3)}\uput{4mm}[-90](\x,3){\scriptsize$\x$}}
    \rput[r](10,1.8){\scriptsize Made in Japan}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the error

> Dictionary stack:    --dict:756/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--
> --dict:75/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: Permission denied Current file position is 69 GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3:
> Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--
> Operand stack:
> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)
> Execution stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run
> --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   run   run   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3
> %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3
> %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2
> --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   run Dictionary stack:    --dict:756/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: Permission denied
> Current file position is 69 GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable
> error, exit code 1 Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run-- Operand stack:
> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)
> Execution stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run
> --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   run   run   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3
> %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3
> %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2
> --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   run Dictionary stack:    --dict:756/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: Permission denied
> Current file position is 69 GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable
> error, exit code 1 Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run-- Operand stack:
> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)
> Execution stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run
> --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   run   run   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3
> %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3
> %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2
> --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   run Dictionary stack:    --dict:756/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: Permission denied
> Current file position is 69 GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable
> error, exit code 1  ) Output written on testint2021.pdf (1 page).
> SyncTeX written on testint2021.synctex.gz. Transcript written on
> testint2021.log.

All packages are up to date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated your MacTeX 2021 since then?

Comment: The issue started when I updated to MacTeX 2021. In 2020 they worked.

Comment: That is not what I asked. MacTeX 2021 needs to be updated, have you updated it?

Comment: Yes, I have updated all packages with TeXLive.

Comment: I just got advice to use xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" in command line. However, my problem is that I'm using pstricks for my book which I edit in TeXShop. I tried to add -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E” after the XeLaTeX command in the preferences but that did not seem to make any difference.  Could somebody help me and suggest how to test the command in TeXShop?

Comment: I think the case is now solved. I was able to the textindy.engine file at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376649/adding-a-new-engine-in-texshop to the following: #! /bin/bash
PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
bfname=${1%\.*}
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" "$bfname" and now everything seems to work perfectly.

Comment: using `lualatex` instead of `xelatex` is much more easier

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is now solved. I was able to modify the textindy.engine part at [Adding a new engine in TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376649/adding-a-new-engine-in-texshop) and do the following:

I saved the text below as ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/XeLaTeXNew.engine on my Mac

#! /bin/bash PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH} bfname=${1%.*} xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" "$bfname"

Then, in the terminal, I run the command

sudo chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/XeLaTeXNew.engine

to set the executable bit on the file.

Finally, I restarted TexShop, and everything runs fine again.

I would like to thank everybody who helped to solve the problem, but especially Herbert Voss for giving the advice of using xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" to fix the original issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hope you should say special thanks to `Herbert Voss` who is the main person of `PsTricks`

Comment: It is also possible to copy the file `/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg`. into a local directory `/.../texlive/texmf-local/dvipdfmx/` and then replace the only valid line from `dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg` into the local `dvipdfmx.cfg`.  Then you can use `xetex` as usual and no changes to the editor are needed.